# Legowelt random sound

Tags: synthesizer, analog

How is Legowelt producing the main sound that you hear at 4:44 in this video? He lists the instruments he uses in this session at the beginning of the clip. He presses some buttons also to effect the sound, repeating a section of it at 4:51. The sound is reminiscent also of Boards of Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try taking a saw or square wave, put on a 4 pole LPF filter with lots of resonance close to, or even into, self oscillation.  Then either run the cutoff through a sample-and-hold LFO, or sequence it by hand.

Resample if you are running it through the LFO.

Then run it through a reverb unit.  You probably want a medium-ish tail, with little to no pre delay, and attenuation on the high frequencies.  Maybe 100% wet?  Try it.  If you do add some dry signal, you'll want to roll off the high end as well.

that should get you close.